# How does constant remain when delta approaches 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I was looking over the following equations.

> $$x(t+\Delta t)\cong x(t)+kx(t)\Delta t-a\Delta t$$ and the unit on both sides is $\text{oryx(es)}$. If we let $\Delta t$ approach $0$, then we get the differential equation $$\frac{dx}{dt}=kx-a$$

How was the second one obtained from the first?

If $\Delta t$ approaches $0$, then how come the constant $a$ still appears in the second equation? $a\Delta t$ should be $0$ when $\Delta t$ approaches $0$, right?

Comment: Because you are "dividing" by $\Delta t$ before $\Delta t \to 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally,
$$
\frac{x(t+\Delta t) - x(t)}{\Delta t} \approx k x(t) +a,
$$
and in the limit as $\Delta t \to 0$,
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = kx(t)+a.
$$